# unable to update UnitPrice field in Opportunity line item

Tags: field-update, opportunity-lineitem

I am executing following code to update `UnitPrice` in  `Opportunity line item`:

```
OpportunityLineItem oli = [SELECT UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = '00k8E000007TzxjQAC'];
oli.UnitPrice = 10;
update oli;
```

After updating the `UnitPrice`, the field keeps its original value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to update the UnitPrice with same quote you posted. Are you using a non-standard pricebook? and is there any inetgration that syncs quotes?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I am using non-standard pricebook. Why?